# Un-disabling alert() in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, disabled-control

I have acidentally disabled alerts on codepen.io and I need it for a website I am making. I pressed the "Prevent this page from making additional dialogs." Please tell me that there is a way to fix it. I have looked at all the other questions towards fixing, but none of them work. Closing and reopening the tab will not work either. Please help!

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the following JavaScript:

   alert('first');
   alert('second');
2. Click OK on the first alert.
3. Check "Prevent this page from making additional dialogs." and click OK on the second alert.
4. Reload the page.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just close your browser and re-open it.  It is not permanent.